# Delete instances on particular points

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I have this geometry setup and I’m wondering what would be an easy way to delete points where I have cylinders (red points)? Basically, my goal is to make space for the cylinders and not overlap with the other circle.
[image: result]
[image: geometry node setup]

Comment: Hello and welcome Licheff. A .blend will help a lot because it's a bit fastidious to have to copy by hand your set up. You can upload it here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `Geometry Proximity` node, you can compare the distance of your points to the faces of the cylinder instances, and delete the ones that are too close:

[image]

[image]

Be aware that realizing instances and calculating the distance between each face and the distributed points is a relatively expensive operation. Feeding `Geometry Proximity` with the resampled curve you're putting your cylinders on would be faster—**1.1*ms*** vs **0.12*ms*** in this instance, so about **9** times faster. However, since that would not take into account the 3D animation of the cylinders (you're not looking at their faces in 3D, just their origin points), you either have to widen the open zone around the deleted points so the clouds would be smaller, or be OK with cylinders penetrating the clouds:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking at the proximity node and the capture attribute but I couldn't figure out the right order to connect them. Since I removed the X rotation of the cylinders, I think the solution without realizing the instances works okay. Thanks again!

Comment: @Licheff You're welcome. Also, just realized that you don't actually need the `Capture Attribute` node here at all, since the positions are already accounted for in the `Delete Geo` calculation and nothing happens to them in between.